# How can I get TaskExecutionTime in C# Task Parallel Library?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I'm using Task Library and using Wait with timeout parameter. How can I set taskExecutionTime?

```
int taskExecutionTime=5000;
try
{
    bool hasTimeout=!myTask.Wait(5000);
    if (!hasTimeout)
       taskExecutionTime=???     
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
    taskExecutionTime=???
}
```

UPDATE:

I don't need real time performance of myTask. For example I'm using .NET's HtpWebRequest with different proxies. I want to know and compare proxy performances. Generic solution will be better, so everyone of us can use it.

Comment: What exactly should `taskExecutionTime` contain? Time since the `Task` started executing? Or how long did you wait? Do you start the `Task` by yourself, or does some other part of the application do that?

Comment: I don't need real time reporting. I'm using .Net's WebRequest with Proxy.  I want to know response performance of proxy. But more generic implemantation can be used everywhere. In summary, I need total Running time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doing a Wait call, I would think you would just time it the normal way you would synchronous code - Stopwatch.StartNew() or var startTime = DateTime.Now or whatever right when you start the task, then look at the elapsed time when the Wait returns false or throws.

Am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Comment: No. You got point. And your solution acceptable. I'll accept it if there is no alternative answer. TPL is so cool library. I think there must be another solution for this requirement like extensions etc. I don't want to repeat my code. I want to get it as myTask.ExecutionTime if possible.

Comment: You're free to subclass Task if you wanted to add this, or have some common method used that keeps a hash of tasks with their start times, or whatever.